# how can i stop other people from seeing/using my .bat file in notebook (notes or smth, i dont know the english name of the app)

Tags: batch-file, passwords, locking

im making a program with .bat and people can login in their accounts but now, people can just look into the file and see the code and the passwords. ive tried many things but i just cant do it. does anyone know how to do this?
where # are shown it was some private info. i tried making it only view in settings but it didnt work (or i did it wrong)

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO hello, what is your name? (no capital letters)

:account
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==######## goto #########
if %cho%==######### goto #########
if %cho%==########## goto ##########
if %cho%==######### goto ##########
ECHO not an account
goto account

:#######
ECHO enter password
set/p "passw=>"
if NOT %passw%==###### goto invalidpassword
if %passw%==####### goto welcome########

:welcome#######
ECHO rank=10
set "rank=10"
ECHO welcome #######, what would you like to do?
goto command

:##########
ECHO enter password
set/p "passw=>"
if NOT %passw%==###### goto invalidpassword
if %passw%==##### goto welcome#########

:welcome###### 
ECHO rank=
set "rank=10"
ECHO welcome #####, what would you like to do?
goto command

:######
ECHO enter password
set/p "passw=>"
if NOT %passw%==####### goto invalidpassword
if %passw%==####### goto welcome#####

:welcome##### 
ECHO rank=10
set/p "rank=10"
ECHO welcome #####, what would you like to do?
goto command


:command
set/p "command=>"
if %command%==player.###### goto player.###########
if %command%==player.########### goto player.############
if %command%==player.######## goto player.#######
if %command%==player.###### goto player.#######
if %command%==player.##### goto player.#######
if %command%==player.###### goto player.######
if %command%==playerlist goto playerlist
if %command%==commandlist goto commandlist
if %command%==help goto help
goto invalidcommand


:player.steefjeiscool
if %rank%==1 goto notallowed 
if %rank%==2 goto notallowed 
if %rank%==3 goto notallowed 
if %rank%==4 goto notallowed 
if %rank%==5 goto notallowed
ECHO private ###################################################################################### ################################################################################################### ########################################################################################
pause
goto command

:player.########
ECHO private ##################################################################################### ################################################################################################## #############################################################################
pause
goto command

:player.private
ECHO private ##################### ################################# ##################### ########## ################ ######################## ########################################## #################################################
pause
goto command

:player.#######
ECHO private ###################################################################################### ##############################################################################################
pause
goto command

:commandlist
ECHO commandlist |shows a list of all the commands|
ECHO playerlist |shows a list of all the people that play on ####### (if a username is not added, dm ###### on #######)|
ECHO player.{name of player}
ECHO 
ECHO 
ECHO 
ECHO 


:playerlist
ECHO private (player)
ECHO private (player)
ECHO private (######)
ECHO private (player)
ECHO private (player)
ECHO private (player)
ECHO private (player)
ECHO .
ECHO .
ECHO .
ECHO .

:help
ECHO this is a program that will give you most of  te information about the server and the players.
ECHO use the command "commandlist" to see all commands
ECHO the server ###### is: ##########

:invalidcommand
ECHO invalid command
goto command

:notallowed
ECHO you do not have acces to this information
pause
goto command

:invalidpassword
ECHO invalid password
pause
goto end

:end
```

Comment: The best advice I can offer is not to use a batch file at all for this type of thing.

Comment: Only true way would be to use a compiler language like C, rust, etc.

Comment: You could give Dave Benham's [Obfuscate.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7990&start=15#p53278) a try.

Comment: No way I let an obfuscated script run on my computer - unless I completely understand what it does. Usually after deobfuscation I find out, it's not worth running it.

Comment: so i shouldnt use an obfuscated script? @Stephan

Comment: It's your choice. My head does "What the heck do they want to hide from me?" In my experience, it usually isn't "protection of intellectual property" (more like "hiding bad coding skills"). De-obfuscating isn't that hard, just very time-consuming. As I said - it's your choice, but let me say: there are several questions here like "after running that obfuscated script, I got problem X - What did it do and how do I revert it?" Most of the time, that problems weren't even intentional, but bad scripting (and of course hard to impossible to revert).

Comment: @thom to get a bit more context - is this .bat file a just-for-fun thing? Like a game between friends?

As has been highlighted in other comments, there's no way to stop the people you give the file to from editing it themselves and changing the behaviour (e.g. removing the need for a password)

If all you're wanting to do is make sure they can't open the file and see the passwords you've assigned for all the users then gideoncalv's answer is a pretty good one

Comment: @pjpscriv this is for my friends and some people i know from an online server. the program is ment to give users information about the server and players but some information is restricted for rank 5 or below. but now, people can just look into the code and see the passwords of the accounts that have higher ranks and use those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain most people use SHA-2 or something similar to hash passwords.
You can use python to hash the password when it is established, and then store that hash to your database. When a user enters their password, hash it and compare that hash with the stored one. This should be secure since SHA-2 is a one-way hash function, and cannot be directly "decoded." This way, the password is never directly stored anywhere, but still works as intended.

Comment: This is almost a good answer, but a better answer would take advantage of the built in Windows utility `certutil` and provide example code instead of just speaking in hypotheticals. That said, if users are able to access the source code (and they apparently can, based on the question), they can just change the hash of the account they want to access to a known hash and log in that way.

Comment: When they can read the script, nothing stops them to alter the `if` command itself. No hash needed, just most basic programming skills necessary (even able to understand English should be enough)

Comment: i dont understand what certutil is but this file is ment to just be send trough mail and be used without them seeing the passwords by looking into the code